# Samsung Galaxy S6 - Camera specifications for tracking

Tags: tracking

I'm trying to use footage from my Samsung Galaxy S6 for tracking in Blender but I don't understand the camera settings. Focal length and sensor width confuses me.

I've used a sensor width of 5,8 mm and a focal length of 4,3 mm. I got those settings from the "Phone tester" app.

*Average error of about 300*.

Comment: Welcome Funkaloss :) Are you sure that the focal lenght is 4.3? 4.5mm is a wide angle fisheye lens that captures 180 degree field of view, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisheye_lens. As far I can see here: http://www.anandtech.com/show/9146/the-samsung-galaxy-s6-and-s6-edge-review/8 it's a fixed *28mm* lens, right?

Comment: Thank you @poor, I'll try that. In the anandtech link you provided it says "4.3 mm (28 mm eff)". I looked at the Samsung Galaxy S4 camera preset in Blender and it says 4.2 mm. In an article about that phone anandtech says "4.2 mm (31 eff)". That's what confused me.